# laravel middleware is working in global group but not in the route group

Tags: php, laravel

I have a middleware which works fine when I place it in the global middleware group in the `Kernel.php` however I don't want the middleware to run on every request so I registered the middleware in the route group but it is not woking even though it is shown when I run `route:list`

Kernel.php related code :

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    'barber' => \App\Http\Middleware\Barber::class,
];
```

web.php related code :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/user', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'barber']], function () {
    // routes
});
```

**Edit :**

I have added the related middleware code and updated the name of the middleware in the question

the middleware code :

```
class Barber
{
    
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();


        if(!$user->active)
        {
            $barber = $user->user_id == 0? false:true;
            return response()->view('user.suspended', ['barber' => $barber]);

        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

any ideas ?

Comment: What does your middleware do? How do you know that it wasn't executed?

Comment: Your code is fine,problem on your middleware

Comment: Could you try changing the case of `\App\Http\Middleware\myMiddleware` to `\App\Http\Middleware\MyMiddleware`.

Maybe it is messed up because of the OS casing interpretation in Windows vs Linux.

Comment: @Remul I know it was not executed because when I register it to the global middlewares array it works fine and redirect the current user to the suspended page. the middleware simply redirect the current user if he is suspended.

Comment: @STA the middleware is fine because it works exactly as intended when I place it in the global middleware array

Comment: @motia the actual name is Barber I have renamed it in the question so when people see the question in the future they don't get lost, and I have tried renaming the key in caps and small but no luck

Comment: I have updated the question, @STA